# What are the benefits of not killing prison guards?

Tags: the-witcher-2

After struggling and failing several times to get a grasp on The Witcher 2's stealth mechanics, I abandoned all hope of being able to sneak through the entire prison in the prologue and decided that everyone who opposed me would die by my blade. Once I escaped from the prison, the person responsible for my freedom scowled at me, saying that I wasn't supposed to create a bloodbath. While I agree, I'm not willing to repeat this sequence however many times I must to not kill anybody unless the rewards are worth it. What benefits do I get for sneaking out of jail?

Comment: I bet it just changes some dialog. I don't know if there's only two options (bloodbath v. not a bloodbath) or a gradient scale.

Comment: It changes some dialog, for me he expressed surprise that it didn't end up in a blood bath. No idea what else it could affect.

Answer (score 2):

The change made by sneaking out is not worth mentioning,as Fabian sad it is happy face instead the sarcastic one and some more exp points.

The thing i saw recently is that there is an alternate path that leads out of dungeon and it has a bit different story.Never tried it myself so maybe it is only beta or console version but check it out.

Comment: Wow. That looks quite different from the finished game.